# Referenced assembly does not have strong name, and it shouldn't

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, assemblies

I'm trying to do instrumented profiling in Visual Studio. Since it has to instrument the binaries, I have turned off assembly signing in all the assemblies in my project.

However, when building, a couple of my assemblies are getting this error: `Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly XXX does not have a strong name`. **The assemblies being compiled are not signed.** I've already turned that off.

To be specific, I have assemblies: NEL, NC, FP, SR, which depend on each other in that order (NC depends on NEL, FP depends on NC and NEL, etc). I have turned off signing in all the assemblies. FP is complaining that NEL and NC do not have strong names. This does not make any sense to me, since FP is not being signed it should not have any trouble referencing another unsigned assembly. Also, NC does not complain about NEL being unsigned.

I've done several clean->rebuild cycles. This does not fix the problem.

I've tried removing the references in VS and readding them. This did not help.

I've checked in the `FP.csproj` file and found `<SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>`, as expected, and nothing else that would indicate to me that the assembly should be signed.

Existing solutions on stackoverflow point to ways to sign the assembly. This is not what I want to do; I want to have my assemblies be unsigned so that VS can instrument them for profiling.

So how do I fix this, so I can build all my assemblies unsigned and use the instrumenting profiler?

Comment: Make very sure that the top project (FP) also is not signed.

Comment: It's not. I've unchecked the "sign this assembly" box for all projects in the solution. I've verified and reverified it for FP. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: To be clear, they were signed before? It's one of those shouldn't happen things. Clean, Rebuild, Restart VS, Restart PC, Reinstall, Reformat. In that order.

Comment: Yeah, they were signed before.

Comment: Well, something got stuck. Pay close attention to the Ouptut window when compiling and/or use MsBuild. Also clean your folders very thoroughly, and reverify all references etc. Search for duplicates of those DLLs, etc. You have a misconfiguration. Always at a place you're sure is fine / not involved.

Comment: There is no programming question here. You simply need to go back and double-check everything. _Something_ is still requiring a signed assembly; there's not enough context for anyone except you to figure out what that is.